# EclipseME - Breakpoints problem

Tags: java, breakpoints, eclipseme

In EclipseME project i have problems with breakpoints that never get hit.
I have set a breakpoint on setTitle that never gets hit. If i change the title, the app shows the title correctly. Does any1 have similar problem?

Im debugging the app on wireless toolkit emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially insulting answer, but are you actually running it in debug mode?

In the interests of full disclosure, I ask this because I've done it myself in the past.

Comment: yes i am. i have a client that is referencing another project. If i set breakpoint in client breakpoint gets hit, but it dont get hit in referenced project...

Comment: Interesting. If you set breakpoints in other locations of your referenced project are those hit?

You say that the breakpoint is on setTitle() and that you change the title, with the app showing this change correctly. Is there the possibility that it's a different setTitle() being called in the class hierarchy?

Comment: Not ideal, but could you break just before you go into your referenced project then step through the code, to the bit you are interested in.